# Limiting simultaneous asynchronous $http get request in angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a page with a table of ip addresses connecting to a media stream. I linked them to a db that includes location info and am able to serve duplicate ips requests from cache to reduce the load. However the page crashes and gives `Error: Insufficient Resources` when too many requests are made at once. I tried batching with [this](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-http-batcher) but I got deprecation warning about `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on main thread` and it didn't seem to help anyway. How do I limit the number of searches done at once? I don't want to limit them to one at a time since it will take too long otherwise. Here is relevant code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(conn, key){

    $http.get("addrinfo.cgi?action=get&addr="+conn.ip, { cache: true}) //$scope.results is list of ip addresses
                    .then(function(ipLocation) {
                        console.log(ipLocation);
                        var locationResults = ipLocation.data; 
                        conn.country = locationResults.country;
                        //... more assignments
                    });
                });
```

Edit: I am having issues implementing Paul's answer. Keep getting `RequestManager is undefined` structure of code looks like this.

```
angular.module('ip-module', [
'app.controller',
'app.filter',
'app.factory'
]);

app.controller('ip-analysis', function($scope, $http, $q) { ... })

.filter('customNumFilter', function() { ... })

.factory('RequestManager', ['$http', '$scope', function() { ... 
}]);
```

Comment: Modify your endpoint to accept multiple addresses in one request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a manager that will handle the requests. The manager can keep track of the number of requests running, and once a limit is reached, redirect the excess requests into a queue. After a request is completed, and there are enough slots, then the next request from the queue can be picked up and run.

```
import copy

angular.module('your-module', []) 

.controller('Controller1', function(){
  .... 
}) 

.controller('Controller1', function(){
  .... 
})

.factory('RequestManager', function(){
  var manager = {
    limit: 10,
    queue: [],
    cache: {},
    requests: 0,
    sendRequest: function(conn){
      if(manager.requests < manager.limit){
        if conn.ip in manager.cache.keys():
          conn.update(manager.cache[conn.ip])
        else:
          manager.runRequest(conn);
      }else{
        manager.queue.push(conn);
      }
    },
    runRequest: function(conn){
      manager.requests++;
      $http.get("addrinfo.cgi?action=get&addr="+conn.ip, { cache: true})
        .then(function(ipLocation) {
            console.log(ipLocation);
            var locationResults = ipLocation.data; 
            conn.country = locationResults.country;
            //... more assignments
            manager.cache[conn.ip] = copy.deepcopy(conn) #use deepcopy to make sure the value is not overwritten in the $scope
            runNextRequest();
        }, function(error){
          runNextRequest();
        });
    },
    runNextRequest: function(){
      if(manager.requests > 0){
        manager.requests --;
        if(queue.length > 0){
          manager.runRequest(queue.shift());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return manager;
}
```

In your controller you could do something like

```
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(conn, key){
  RequestManager.sendRequest(conn);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how you use the values, but you can tweak the code to use them more appropriately.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't had time to run this code so watch out for possible errors.

Comment: I put this at the end of my controller and I'm getting `RequestManager is undefined`. Do I need to inject the dependencies?

Comment: you would need to add the factory to your angular module. I modified the code so you can see how it will relate to your angular module.

Comment: Before I just had `app.controller` with no module. now I have this `angular.module('ip-module',[]) .controller('ip-controller', function($scope, $http, $q){ ... }) .filter('addZero', function() { ... }) .factory('RequestManager', ['$http', '$scope', function(){ ... }]);` Now I'm getting `Unknown Provider addZero filter`

Comment: You'll need to add your factories as dependencies to the controller using it.
Something like .controller('ip-controller', function($scope, $http, $q, addZero, RequestManager){ .. })

Comment: I have this now but the error `Unknown provider: addZeroFilterProvider`     ,`angular.module('ip-module',[]) .controller('ip-controller', function($scope, $http, $q, addZero, RequestManager){ ... }) .filter('addZero', function() { ... }) .factory('RequestManager', ['$http', '$scope', function(){ ... }]);`

Comment: So I was able to get it to work by working it into an object in the controller instead of a factory. Now I have to find the limit that gives the best performance without crashing it. Is there a way to check the cache so that duplicate results skip the queue and served automatically from the cache? Thank you.

Comment: Cool :) You could add a map field in the RequestManager to keep track of the results that were already returned. So, like add cache: { }, and then after the result is returned, you do manager.cache[ip] = value. That way, before you call runRequest(), you can check in your controller if it has already been requested before like .. if ip in RequestManager.cache.keys(): return RequestManager.cache[ip] else: RequestManager.runRequest(...) etc

Comment: Oh, another way to do it would be in runRequest(). Where you do if conn.ip in cache.keys(): conn.country = cache[ip].country ... else: manager.runRequest(conn). I'll add that in the code snippet to make it easier to understand